# SNMP OID for CPU model information

Tags: linux, snmp, central-processing-unit

I am currently trying to find the oid / way to gather the CPU model name from a server using SNMP. I have tried looking up the specific oid for it however all I could find were ones that related to CPU usage and not what I needed. Unless I missed it, I could not find it on http://www.mibdepot.com/ either.

Would appreciate any help that the community could offer to gather this information via SNMP

Comment: Have you found anything on this subject?